# hook_node_load for currently viewed node?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I am trying to modify $node via [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) but I do not have the current node in the list of $nodes handled by hook_node_load when I check it with [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)'s dpm. I only have some nodes from a node_load_multiple call I make in the module. Should I use [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) instead? But hook_node_view says it can only modify node content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when and where you trying to modify the $node. hook_node_load runs every time a node is loaded,whereas  hook_node_view runs only when a node is about to be rendered on the page.

The reason you might not be having the node id in question in you hook_node_load may be because the context in which you are calling hook_node_load might be wrong.
In order to test you can create a dummy callback and call the node_load() in it with you nid in question. You can see that once you call the node_load() api, it will invoke a call to hook_node_load.

Cheers